# Amazon SES PHPMail or SDK

Tags: php, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I've registered with Amazon SES service with email limit setup and out of the sandbox. I've tried many PHPMailer function and all return me as error : Connexion time out (110). Is it possible the send mail from PHPMailer?

I have seen on Amazon SES site this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html).

```
<?php

// Replace path_to_sdk_inclusion with the path to the SDK as described in 
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/quick-start.html
define('REQUIRED_FILE','path_to_sdk_inclusion'); 

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
define('SENDER', 'sender@example.com');           

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
define('RECIPIENT', 'recipient@example.com');    

// Replace us-west-2 with the AWS region you're using for Amazon SES.
define('REGION','us-west-2'); 

define('SUBJECT','Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)');
define('BODY','This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.');

require REQUIRED_FILE;

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',     
    'region' => REGION
));

$request = array();
$request['Source'] = SENDER;
$request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
$request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
$request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = BODY;

try {
     $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
     $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
     echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

} catch (Exception $e) {
     echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ");
     echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
}

?>
```

I've copy all the codes, put my variable instead of showned in the demo script. Now I'm getting the error : You must use KEY ans SECRET_KEY to use this script... Where I cant put my KEY and SECRETKEY in the script? There is no explanation on how to do this.

Is there another way send email throught Amazon SES service?
Thanks!

Comment: It's step 1 in the link you posted.

Comment: I know that. There were created : AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. My question is where must I use this in the script example. Is it like <? php define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID','xxxxxxxxxxxxx'); ?> ?

Comment: Nowhere. If they're in the environment the SDK will pick them up automatically. If you don't want to use env variables, again, see the link in step 1.

Comment: Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide that your error will link to, and do the steps to check your environment to be sure you're not being blocked by your ISP. For SMTP access, I would expect you to put your access keys in message headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple. I have to add key and secret in :

```
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',     
    'region' => REGION,
     'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    )
));
```

and set XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX full access to api in amazon security credentials

Comment: arghhh ... how on earth was anyone supposed to guess that ... way to go amz for obsfucating your api's.  I ended up using php's `putenv`, albeit suboptimal. I prefer yours.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know PHP Mailer was not working with AWS SES by API, you should use SES SMTP with PHP Mailer.

The correct ports are 25, 465 or 587.

Comment: I haved tried about everything with PHPMailer with SMTP and all port you mention get the same results : time out error (110)

Comment: I've add a SMTP server in my personal mail client Mail OSX and I'm laughing right now. It works in this way. Why it's so complicated with a simple PHP script

Comment: Check PHP Mailer configuration and change timeout value to 1 or 2 min, Also, enabling debug log by   $Mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;

Comment: PHPMailer's default timeout is 5 minutes, as per the RFC spec. It's not complicated, you just need to make sure your network is letting you out. Are you running PHPMailer on the same machine as Apple Mail?

Comment: @synchro no PHPMailer is on a web server and they dont block amazon ses...

Comment: So it's on a completely different network! Apparently they do block, or you wouldn't be getting the error. Do the tests in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) on the web server.